# MSCRM 4.0 - Send Emails to marketing list members

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm very new to Microsoft CRM. I'm currently using Microsoft CRM 4.0. I want to send e-mail to all members of a marketing list but using E-Mail activity not the campaign of marketing lists. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Campaign? If you want to use a marketing list but not use Campaign I Think you need to use something like Mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a very basic plugin that queries for all members of the marketing list and drops them into the To field of an email (or separate emails if that's what you prefer).  You could even call the Send method within the plugin

Note: recipients in CRM are activity parties, so you would just create a list of ActivityParty and have an activity party for each marketing list member.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you trigger the plugin?

Comment: you have dozens of options.  The two most straightforward in my opinion would be 1) you could set up some sort of custom entity that triggers it on create (or update of a certain field on it).  2) you could use one of the OOB entities and put a flag field on it (like a campaign) that becomes the triggering mechanism.  If you have special requirements on needing to send it nightly or on a periodic basis, you could trigger it via workflows or bulk deletion jobs... basically any way you can trigger a plugin could be used here.

Comment: True, viable option, so is creating a windows service that does a lot of things :)

Comment: A windows service could work and would have a great deal of flexibility.  Often in my Production environments, getting a service created approved requires outside people to do an entire architectural review and outside parties to take part in approving.  I try to keep my customizations contained to just CRM so that I don't have to go through all these layers of red tape.